# Can we have constructor for a nested class?

Tags: c#

```
In the below example i want to create folder in nested class constructor:

    namespace Nm
    {
        class Outer
        {
            private const string s1 = "@.\bin";

            void O1()
            {
                Nested nestedFile = new Nested();
                nestedFile.FileName = "Queue1";
            }
        }

        internal class Nested
        {
            public string FileName
            {
                set
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(s1); // !
                    fileName = s1+ value + ".dat";
                    Console.writeLine(fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely - same way as you would normally:

```
class Outer
{
    private void Foo()
    {
        Nested nested = new Nested("bar");
    }

    class Nested
    {
        internal Nested(string x)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK.I have 1st instantiated nested class did some processing/validation. then at some point, the outer class changes the value of s1 , then?

Comment: @starz26: strings in .NET are immutable so every time you changed it - you create a new instance. So anyway outer string changes will not affect a string passed to a nested class

Comment: @starz26, if it's const, you can't change the value, but if you make it a private field member and pass an instance of the Outer class to the Nested constructor, the Nested constructor can access the private field.  This is one of the primary benefits of Nested classes, as it allows you to have the benefit of class encapsulation (to organize responsibilities), but where you still need to share tightly coupled state.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you class is `internal` (not Outer-`private`), you can do next:

```
class Outer
{
    internal const string s1 = "@.\bin";
}

internal class Nested
{
    public string FileName
    {
        set
        {
            Outer.s1;field
        }
    }
}
```

But any class in your assembly will have access to this field